# How to eliminate all not chat-related from the Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I do not want to see anything from the facebook what is not chat-related, like:

- the integrated facebook browser (yes, it is not a joke)
- popups of my pals currently logged in
- excerpts of their facebook posts
- many-level influence of my phone GUI (like flooding of my sharing possibilities by my messenger contacts)

My goal is to entirely eliminate facebook from my life, *except the messenger chat and video calls, because I can talk with some people only there*.

The best would be an opensource app which knows the facebook messenger protocol, and serves exactly this purpose. Alternatively, not opensource apps, or the tunings/settings of the currently available apps would also do.

Comment: [Meta post](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/494/50837) about the topicality of borderline software recommendation questions.